# spring data jpa "between" keyword

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

`findByPointsBetween(Integer lowerlimit,Integer upperlimit);`
is above equivalent to `lowerlimit < Points < upperlimit` , or `lowerlimit <= Points <= upperlimit`.

I want to write `lowerlimit <= Points <= upperlimit`, for some query, can anybody help me to clarify the **Between** keyword, and help me to write my spring data jpa query, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think variant `lowerlimit <= Points <= upperlimit` is true. Because spring-data translate this to JPQL. And [JPQL spec](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_between) use this variant.

Answer (score 1):

Between keyword works like "lowerlimit <= Points <= upperlimit".
Between keyword in Spring Data Jpa is equal to this is Jpql:

```
… where x.startDate between ?1 and ?2
```

where Jpql between works with included boundaries.
You can also test it by running a repository method using between and see the results. Put 1,2,3 to DB and call it like:

```
findByPointsBetween(1,2);
```